# Is 'feature extraction' a core machine learning task?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction, pattern-recognition

I have been arguing with a friend about ‘feature extraction’. He says the main task of ML is to extract features. But I disagree. In a common-sense feature extraction is not an ML task. If we consider wx+b as the simplest way to represent ML, the task of ML is to find the best w and b. x is the feature. ML tries to find out the best w and b values for a given x, it matches with the training data and thus learns how to find w and b.

My friend says it is the core task of ML to extract features. But as I know feature extraction is a data preprocessing task mainly.

Comment: If you know this to be the case, what is your question?

Comment: If you define 'ML' as the model itself, then feature extraction is not a core step. If you define 'ML' as 'what it takes to build an ML solution', the definitely feature extraction is a core step. I would go with the latter.

Comment: @Stergios Thanks for your valuable comment. I understand both scenarios now. But is it the only core task an ML does? And sometimes the feature extraction can be done manually.

I want to ask you this, is feature extraction itself is machine learning or it is a process of machine learning?

Comment: It's not the only core task in my opinion. Feature extraction is part of the process of building an ML-based solution. The term "machine learning" itself is mostly focused on the algorithms and statistics but in any realistic project ML is much broader than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting features is an important job in ML. Without features you cannot find the best "w" and "b". If you are able to find w and b without feature extraction then you don't really need to go forward with ML.